# Yii custom DbLogRoute with YII_DEBUG shows traces in message

Tags: php, logging, yii

I have a custom DbLogRoute that accepts a CJSON::encoded array instead of 'message'. The data is decoded and put in proper places etc. That part works as it should.

The problem arises when I have YII_DEBUG set to true.

For some reason the encoded data is being appended with debug info and cannot be decoded as a JSON anymore. Example:

```
{"message":"Success","execution":84,"filename":"test.xml"}
in /projectdir/www/protected/components/CustomApplicationComponent.php (39)
in /projectdir/www/protected/components/ImportFile.php (750)
in /projectdir/www/protected/components/CustomApplicationComponent.php (75)
```

The only way I managed to get rid of this is by unsetting YII_DEBUG, but I do need it from time to time and I doubt that's the best solution to this issue.

I cannot show much of the code, but the implementation is based on http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/521/log-activity-in-database/#c14224
except that I also added support for foreign keys and indexes in the log table.

I need a smart brain to help me figure out where this trace enters the picture and how to suppress it!

Comment: Hard to help you without any code. But did you check `YII_TRACE_LEVEL` constant? Check [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging#logging-context-information).

Comment: You, good sir, are the genius I was looking for. I didn't think that the two constants were connected, but looking through the code I was that they were.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @Michael Härtl in the comments. Thank you!

This was caused by `YII_TRACE_LEVEL` constant being set when `YII_DEBUG` was set.